# Add new feature announce box (Modal) when loading the page on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm a beginner to ROR. Currently using Ruby 6.1 . I'm trying to add new feature announce box to inform users about recent changes of the app. This is a web app. This should popup in when accessing the login page automatically and It will function like a cookie notice. Here's a sample template.

[image]

But it currently is not a popup. Confused when to render. I did this code on `app>view>login.html.erb`

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Feature announcement</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Got it</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bootstrap enabled, you can simply use a [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/) and maybe you will also have to use turbo frames. Follow this tutorial to [learn how to create a BS modal with turbo frames](https://www.hotrails.dev/articles/rails-modals-with-hotwire).